# Can the Stack Overflow mobile apps be used with private communties based on Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, support, ios-app, stack-overflow-enterprise

I downloaded both the Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange apps hoping there would be a way to point one of them at a private community based on Stack Enterprise. I'm not seeing a way to do this.

Questions:

1. Is this possible and am I missing it?
2. If not, is it a planned feature?
3. Has anyone modified the app to do this, and if so, how?

Comment: _"a private community based on Stack Enterprise"_ I am not aware about such _private communities_. exist. Did you mean Stack Exchange Teams?

Comment: Just as a general comment:  the development of the apps have been relatively frozen.  It's *unlikely* that they'll support Teams, but someone who actually works here could always prove me wrong.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Those do, see https://stackoverflow.com/enterprise. SO Enterprise is older than teams, and offers more features, such as on-premises hosting and SSO. I don't think you can use any of the apps though.

Comment: The iOS (and Android) apps use [the public API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) which doesn't have any provision for connecting to Enterprise instances.